# How to move all parts to the center, based on selected object

Tags: modeling

I have a gun and its way to off center to use in a game, and I need it to be so that the sight is at the center so that the aim animation is at the center of the screen exactly. So How can I move the whole gun so that the sight is on the cursor or center? I Have many parts to the gun not just one part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to adjust the object pivot point? A lot of rotation and centering problems can happen if an object's pivot point is way off. In the image below, there is a gun and three separate objects. The gun is the parent, and the objects are children. You can see how the gun rotates around the pivot point, and the children follow.
[image]

Using the 3d cursor and the "Set Origin to 3D Cursor" option, you can place your object's pivot point wherever you like, including the barrel or sight. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Method

1. Set the origins to the center.

   - **move** your cursor to the gun.
   - **select** all the objects.
   - **Set** origin to *3D cursor*.
2. Move all objects to the center.

   - **select** all the pieces of the gun.
   - press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.

### Take note.

This will move the **origin** of each object to the center of the grid. That means you must have your 3D cursor in the correct spot when you set the origins. You can press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and choose *snap cursor to selected* to snap the cursor to a specific object.